# How to response a proper server execution to Ajax Post method?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a very simple task in my application, wich retrieves data from a combobox in after its selection event.

When select event is raised, data is passed to a jQuery function which requests opperation from server side.

All these stuffs are ok, but on processing server's response, Ajax receives a fail condition to the request. As I'm a rookie in jQuery and Ajax, I didn't know what I should be missing or doing wrong.

Jsp piece:

```
<input id="updStatus" 
    class="easyui-combobox" 
    name="updStatus"
    data-options="
    valueField:'id',
    textField:'Name',
    url:'StatusListCombo',
    onSelect:function updStatusTask(row) {
      $.fn.updStatusTask(row.id, ${task.id});
    }">
```

jQuery function:

```
$.fn.updStatusTask = function (idStatus, idTask) {
  var result = $.post("TaskUpdateStatus", {
    idTask : idTask, 
    idStatus : idStatus
  });

  result.done(function( data ) {
    alert("data: " + data); //<--NOT REACHED!!
  });
  result.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("fail data: " + textStatus); //FIRED
  });
  result.always(alert("always"));//FIRED
};
```

Serverside method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/TaskUpdateStatus")
public String TaskUpdateStatus(Long idTask, Long idStatus, HttpSession httpSession, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

  String result = new String();
  try {
    //... do DAO opperations to persist, everything Ok...
    resp.setStatus(200);
    result = "Task successfully updated.";
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    result = "Error: " + e.getMessage(); 
  }

  return result;    
}
```

Comment: What's the fail request?

Comment: @enginefree, good question. [data] parameter only shows "Error". Can I get more information on this error?

Comment: instead of doing `e.getMessage()`, just try `e.toString()`.

Comment: @enginefree, no errors are thrown. The problem is during the response's treatment in ajax. Please, see my comments to the answer beneath.

Comment: if you want to provide feedback. Just parse the responce on the `javascript` side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem was the String parameter returned by Controller. It was enough change controller type `TaskUpdateStatus` from `String` to `void`, and, obviously, supress the `return` statement.

Rather, the right way to return a text to the jQuery event handler, to be processed and showed, is using `response.getWritter().write("something")`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/TaskUpdateStatus")
public void TaskUpdateStatus(Long idTask, Long idStatus, HttpSession httpSession, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

  String result = new String();
  try {
    //... do DAO opperations to persist, everything Ok...
    resp.getWriter().write("Status changed from "
          + oldStatusName + " to " +   newStatusName);
    resp.setStatus(200);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    //... take care of exceptions
  }

}
```

No errors is thrown and datum is correctly exhibited in Ajax post `.done` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by annotating

```
public String TaskUpdateStatus(@RequestParam("idTask") Long idTask, @RequestParam("idStatus") Long idStatus, ...
```

otherwise Spring doesn't know where to get those fields and inject them.

Comment: All the tasks are occouring as desired. The only problem is that Ajax is receiving a fail condition after all.

Comment: @Alex Can you tell us what status code it's receiving and what output Spring is providing? It doesn't seem to me like your controller method is being executed.

Comment: Yes, mine controller method is perfectly do executed. Database changes, no errors are thrown (I've steped it through in Debug). It all are acting as expected. Even the jsp page, when updated, shows the new status for the task. But I'd like to provide feedback informing that the opperation was successful (an alert or jeasyui message). I think that is just a matter of correctly manipulate the response, or providing the correct return for the function, anything like this. Thanks for helping!